# XMPP Jabberd2 connection problems

Tags: java, xmpp, jabberd2

I'm trygin to connect to Jabberd2 server that i've created and here is what i do:

```
  ConnectionConfiguration configuration = new;  ConnectionConfiguration("localhost", 5222);
    configuration.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(configuration);
    connection.connect();
```

after `connect();` part i'm getting this error:

```
    stream:error (text)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:260)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:43)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
```

and this is my Smack debug:
Sent:

```
    <stream:stream to="localhost" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0">
    <presence id="iuS06-0" type="unavailable"></presence>
    </stream:stream>
```

Received:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' xmlns='jabber:client' from='localhost' version='1.0' id='yawymcwsfxk8mzlyapv1y5pvgi9ngnpfxmdky9dd' xmlns:ack='http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html#ns'><stream:error xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'><host-unknown xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/><text xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'>service requested for unknown domain</text></stream:error></stream:stream>
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

it turned out i was missing  section under  section in c2s.xml